# How to enable mod_redirect in htaccess over HTTP/2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, debian, http2

I've modified my Debian 9 installation (Apache 2.4.25) to allow HTTP/2 support.

I've successfully checked it online, and the pages *do* serve, but the problem lies with the redirection performed in .htaccess to map for example site.com/index.php/brands/mybrand to a nice url (site.com/brands/mybrand). It simply does not happen. This is a Codeigniter setup.

- The problematic steps seem to be when I disable the current modules (`a2dismod php7.2` and `mpm_prefork`) and I enable a mpm module(`a2enmod mpm_event`, but I also tried `mpm_worker`) that supports HTTP/2.
- At that point I get "file not found" (404 error)
- By reverting those two steps I get back to normal (no HTTP/2 of course)

Is the mod_rewrite.c conditional below invalidated by loading the mpm_worker module? If so how do I replace it?

> EDIT: a detailed Log show me this error:
>   AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n', referer: https://sitename.com/brands/

My .htaccess (in the brands directory where index.php resides) which works fine with the previous configuration is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
IndexOptions +Charset=UTF-8
```

My /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf relevant content includes:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
         # even without enabling here h2c or h2 I get the error
         Protocols http/1.1
         <Directory "/var/www/html">
                 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                 AllowOverride All
                 # since apache 2.4
                  Require all granted
         </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Note: Other commands that I previously run to enable additional modules required are these ones below. I didn't have to touch anything of this to revert back to a working (non HTTP/2) configuration:

```
apt-get install php7.2-fpm
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
a2enconf php7.2-fpm
```

### Edit:

The problem was because of an internal redirect. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not configured PHP-FPM correctly. Disable that php-fpm configuration by saying `a2disconf php7.2-fpm`. And add the following in the httpd.conf file, this should work:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
SetHandler  "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9000"
</FilesMatch>
ProxyErrorOverride On
```

Restart Apache and PHP-FPM (PHP-FPM restart probably not required, but Apache must be restarted). Enable HTTP/2 now, it should work probably.

### Edit

The OP had this problem from some redirect in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I think that makes sense; something is wrong about that. I don't have a httpd.conf in my Debian installation, I have apache2.conf and in conf-available, php7.2-fpm.conf with similar content:

`<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        ProxyErrorOverride on
        Require all granted
    </FilesMatch>
`

Comment: Do what I say, disable that conf. httpd.conf is the same as apache2.conf

Comment: Yep I did enter the configuration above in apache2.conf, disabled the other configuration, restarted php-fpm and apache2 and ... I get the php code in the browser.. somehow it's not been processed by the handler.. As soon as I disable mpm-event and enable php7.2 again, it's all working as before without apparent problems (I left all the modified configuration as it is)

Comment: Oh sorry, I did the wrong regex up there, I have fixed it. check it now

Comment: Thanks for the patience. I did try your edited statement but I get a 503 error in the browser. Without it, the php code shows in the browser (not interpreted) The problem is the sethandler command, most surely. I tried your command in the original  php7.3-fpm.conf (I moved to 7.3 now) and also in apache2.conf (disabling the other conf). Same thing.

Comment: I've just started from scratch and with your configuration, I was able to run a .php script in another folder, no bootstrap. SO it seems the problem is the .htaccess code.. i'll work on that then.

Comment: You get 503 error, because you have PHP-FPM turned off for some reason. Start the php-fpm service, you won't get that problem. You shouldn't use other SetHandler(s) for PHP-FPM/PHP when you are using mine, because it won't work with PHP-FPM. Only use the one I provided or use the default. Make sure you have PHP-FPM service started. Check the default configuration's port for PHP-FPM, it is usually port 9000.

Comment: I was able to solve the redirection problem (that was actually the culprit.. php was alright with your suggested coinfig) with a new .htaccess that I had to dig around the web. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yay, I upvoted you!

Comment: Thanks my friend, marked as answer because I *also* had a mess with php-fpm config. Learned a lot.